# [Titan Example Graph]: copySplit and back not working as expected

Tags: gremlin

The following query of the Titan example graph does not produce what I expected:

```
g.V.has("age", T.lte,1000).as('young').out('battled').has("name","cerberus").copySplit(
  _().back('young'),
  _()
).exhaustMerge
```

it gives me twice the cerberus vertex, instead of `hercules` and `cerberus`

It appears that back is not working after a `copySplit`. Is there a way around this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered on the Gremlin users mailing list, but here we go again:

These 2 alternatives would still work in Gremlin3 (with a slightly different syntax, but the concept is the same):

```
gremlin> g.V().has("age", T.lte, 1000).as("young").out("battled").has("name", "cerberus").as("monster").select()
==>[young:v[24], monster:v[44]]
```

Or:

```
gremlin> g.V().has("age", T.lte, 1000).out("battled").has("name", "cerberus").path()
==>[v[24], v[44]]
```